# why does my python server request remain in limbo while trying to fetch subrequest from redis store (in nginx openresty)?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, redis, openresty

I'm using `srcache` to cache requests to a java server from my flask server.

Now when i try sending requests to my nginx listening on `8080` using Postman, or Jmeter, or from the flask server routed through an ngrok tunnel, there seems to be no issues. The first request throws a cache `MISS` and subsequest requests have a cache `HIT`.

However, when I use my flask server directly, on `localhost:5000`, the requests remains in-flight, and seems to never resolve until i do an `openresty reload`, when it throws an internal server error. :?

Any ideas around this

Here's where the python server fires a request

```
def json_output(text):
url = "http://localhost:8080/?properties={0}".format(ann)
payload = text

print "Payload",payload
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

try:
    data = json.loads(r.text.decode("utf8"))
except Exception as e:
    data = {"sentences":[]}
return data
```

Here's the caching part on openresty nginx:

```
srcache_response_cache_control  off;
srcache_ignore_content_encoding  off;
set_escape_uri  $escaped_key $key;

srcache_fetch  GET /redis $key;

srcache_store  PUT /redis2 key=$key&exptime=60000;
srcache_methods GET POST;
srcache_fetch_skip $skip_fetch;

default_type  application/json;
proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9001;
```

*the same code works fine if the request is routed through an ngrok tunnel though*